# Looping to correct data based in the column name in R

Tags: r, loops

So I have a file with several Dates call it Date.1, Date.2 .. Date.168. There are another columns in the middle. It's not a sequence. So, I would like to correct the format date with a loop code based on column name. I tried this:

```
for(i in 1:168) {final$Date.[i]=as.Date.numeric(as.numeric(as.character(final$Date.[i])),origin = "1899-12-30")}
```

Of course, that my code do not consider `final$Date.[i]` as `final$Date.1`. There is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution.
Not absolutely sure about this, since the question is lacking sample data, but it should work (fast!).

```
library( data.table )
#make final a data.table
setDT( final )
#what are the names of columns we want to change?
cols <- paste0( "Date.", 1:168 )
#update the columns the data.table way (by reference)
dt[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, function(x) as.Date.numeric(as.numeric(as.character(x)),origin = "1899-12-30")), .SDcols = cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign multiple columns at once with `paste0` and `<-`

```
df[paste0("Date.", 1:168)] <- as.Date.numeric(
                                     as.numeric(
                                           as.character(
                                                 as.matrix(df[paste0("Date.", 1:168)])
                                           )
                                     ), 
                                     origin = "1899-12-30"
                              )
```